# Google drive. Connecting to different customer accounts, where do they find key and secret?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

A part of the program I am developing is creating some PDF files for our customers, which I then would like to store on the customers own Google drive.

To make this possible, I need their key and secret to be able to connect to the drive, but how do you find the key and secret for a Google drive account, from the Google drive interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a *really* bad idea to me. There's a reason why it's called a "secret".

What you should do instead is create the documents in *your* Drive account, but then share them with your customers. That way they'll have access to the documents (and can copy them if they wish) but without you getting access to the rest of their documents.

(Note: I work for Google, but nowhere near Drive. This answer represents my personal opinions, not those of Google as a company.)

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am pretty sure our customers would make demands to have them on their personal accounts. These files are extremely important to them, its rapports made by their employees, and if they do not have them when government personnel inspects them, they can loose their license. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Jacob: In that case they would choose to take a copy. The main thing is that *they* can do that. I think it would look far worse if government personnel found out that *you* had access to their drive...

Comment: Dropbox can do this, with apps which gives you access to folders on different accounts. The reason I was looking at Google drive was that there was a C# SDK, and not somthing open source noone has updated for 6 months.

Comment: @Jacob: Well it *is* an open source SDK... you *may* be able to create folders with Google Drive which specific users can add files to, but your original approach of your customers giving you their secret still sounds just plain wrong to me. Would you even dream of asking them for their passwords?

Comment: I do know what open source means, but what I meant was, it is a big risk if somthing is changed and suddenly it stops working. If the account is made only for this, and they could change the password should they want to stop using our system, then I do not see it as a major issue. If it was the account connected to their mail and if the drive had all their other documents then I would never ask for it.

Comment: @Jacob: Perhaps in this case - but you asked for "the customers own Google drive".

Comment: Well what I meant was they could have a drive for these rapports, so they get the sense it on their personal system. I would never try and mix it with 1 of their existing Google accounts. Sorry if that was a bit unclear. The best solution imo is actually what dropbox does where you authorize access for an app to 1 specific folder, and then you can allways terminate the access if you want to, then you do not need several accounts for situations like this, and you do not need any sensitive data from the owner of the account.

Comment: User should be able to give his Google Drive username and password and whenever it uploads the file, the file should be uploaded in their drive. Definitely sharing Client_Id and Client_Secret is no way possible. But logging into Google account is possible. I feel offline Google drive works the same way, login with whatever credentials and files will be uploaded to that user drive. If Jacob got the solution for this then I would request to share that. And Jon, I hope it makes more sense now. Also see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679444/upload-files-on-cloud-using-email-address